# Postgresql LDAP authentication over SSL

Tags: postgresql, ssl, ldap

How do I set up postgresql 9.1 on Ubuntu server 12.04 to use LDAP authentication over SSL against a Windows AD server.

Client SSL is set up and works in postgresql.

LDAP without SSL works.

In pg_hba.conf I have this:

```
hostssl  ldaptest all   0.0.0.0/0 ldap ldapserver="myldapserver.local" ldapprefix="cn=" ldapsuffix=", ou=TestOU, dc=sub, dc=example, dc=local"
```

I am able to connect with psql, though passwords are sent unencrypted as expected.

If I set it to use TLS on normal port (389):

```
hostssl  ldaptest all   0.0.0.0/0 ldap ldapserver="myldapserver.local" ldapprefix="cn=" ldapsuffix=", ou=TestOU, dc=sub, dc=example, dc=local" ldaptls=1
```

I get:

```
could not start LDAP TLS session: error code -11
```

If I set it to use the LDAPS port (636) to use SSL:

```
hostssl  ldaptest all   0.0.0.0/0 ldap ldapserver="myldapserver.local" ldapprefix="cn=" ldapsuffix=", ou=TestOU, dc=sub, dc=example, dc=local" ldaptls=0 ldapport=636
```

I get:

```
LDAP login failed for user "cn=Teszt User,ou=TestOU,dc=sub,dc=example,dc=local" on server "ratotdc.okologia.mta.local": error code -1
```

If I turn on both TLS and set the port to 636 I get:

```
could not start LDAP TLS session: error code -11
```

I have the server certificate in my ldap.conf:

```
TLS_CACERT      /root/certs/infolabtest_cert.cer
```

ldapsearch works over SSL and returns correct results:

```
ldapsearch -W -H ldaps://myldapserver:636/ -D "CN=Teszt User,OU=TestOU,DC=sub,DC=example,DC=local" -b "ou=testou,dc=sub,dc=example,dc=local" "CN"
```

Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Postgres now supports **ldaps://** starting with version 11 according to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/auth-ldap.html)

So the configuration in pg_hba.conf looks like:

```
host  ldaptest all   0.0.0.0/0 ldap ldapulr="ldaps://myldapserver.local:636/ou=testou,dc=sub,dc=example,dc=local?cn?sub"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit more difficult. I found the answer here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol

> A common alternative method of securing LDAP communication is using an
>   SSL tunnel. This is denoted in LDAP URLs by using the URL scheme
>   "ldaps". The default port for LDAP over SSL is 636. The use of LDAP
>   over SSL was common in LDAP Version 2 (LDAPv2) but it was never
>   standardized in any formal specification. This usage has been
>   deprecated along with LDAPv2, which was officially retired in 2003.

Posgres doesn't support LDAPv2 (e.i. ldpas://), **but it does support LDAPv3 TLS**